# Tab key doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-layout

Since a couple of days, my <kbd>Tab</kbd> key doesn't work.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine. For example in a text editor it does nothing, but for example in a form in the browser it blinks/focuses the field but it doesn't jump to the next field of the form. It works fine in my dual-boot Windows installation.

Any ideas as to what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: You can try creating a new user account on your machine. If the problem doesn't occur on a fresh user account, you will know that something is messed up in your personal settings. You will need to reconfigure all your user settings on the new account, but you may find out what the problem is in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have found the solution.
I had autokey installed and it was conflicting with the system. I was sure that I had disable it before to test this but it looks like it was not disabled at all.

swift, your response has helped me understand the problem, so i will give the bounty to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Such conflict or just override can be possible if you use global sharing of your shortcut layouts between applications. Try to check Keyboard Shortcuts in System Settings and your IBus Preferences.

If we talk about Firefox, then also, I was checked - Tab key shortcut preference in FF not exist, however it works, because it's common typing feature.

So, if your layout have shared in global, then Tab key mapped at some app just can't to find their command in other app or just work with error or catch.